# how can I dynamically remove an error at the ng-stepper level?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

I was trying to use this angular HTML

```
<mat-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="gadsForm" [attr.errorMessage]="showStepperError ? firstStepError : null">
```

But regardless of `showStepperError`'s value - the stepper always shows an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `[hasError]` is the only thing that has worked for me:

`<mat-step [stepControl]="gadsForm" [errorMessage]="stepperErrorMessage" [hasError]="stepperErrorMessage !== ''">`

Answer (score 2):

`errorMessage` is an input property for the mat-step component, not an attribute

Please change the `errorMessage` property as shown below:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="gadsForm" [errorMessage]="showStepperError ? firstStepError : null">
```

Comment: I tried this before, but the error always remains. Also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3zhs.png

Comment: It can be fixed by showStepperError ? firstStepError : “” change this condition as follow.

Comment: If it still shows error means can you please share stackblitz?

Comment: can you see my image in the original post? It shows an error with your code. Regardless.

Comment: As i mentioned in the comment: It is typescript error you should set empty string instead of null value: showStepperError ? firstStepError : “”